# Multiple Files on chatter Feed is not showing when created from apex

Tags: apex, chatter-feed, connect-api, chatter-file

I see Chatter post can allow multiple files to be posted at a time in Lightning. But from the below code in Apex, I'm only able to get one file on the chatter post.

```
List<ConnectApi.BatchInput> batchInputs = new List<ConnectApi.BatchInput>();

ConnectApi.FeedItemInput feedItemInput = new ConnectApi.FeedItemInput();
ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput messageBodyInput = new ConnectApi.MessageBodyInput();
ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput textSegmentInput = new ConnectApi.TextSegmentInput();

messageBodyInput.messageSegments = new List<ConnectApi.MessageSegmentInput>();
textSegmentInput.text = 'Testing';    
feedItemInput.body = messageBodyInput;
feedItemInput.feedElementType = 
ConnectApi.FeedElementType.FeedItem;
feedItemInput.subjectId = subjectId;        

feedItemInput.capabilities = new 
ConnectAPI.FeedElementCapabilitiesInput();
feedItemInput.capabilities.files = new ConnectAPI.FilesCapabilityInput();
feedItemInput.capabilities.files.items = new List<ConnectAPI.FileIdInput>();

List<Id> fileIds = new List<Id>();
fileIds.add('06922000000dMR8AAM');
fileIds.add('06922000000dMR7AAM');

for(Id conDoc : fileIds){
    ConnectAPI.FileIdInput attachFile = new 
    ConnectAPI.FileIDInput();        
    attachFile.id = conDoc;
feedItemInput.capabilities.files.items.add(attachFile);            
}
ConnectApi.BatchInput batchInput = new 
ConnectApi.BatchInput(feedItemInput);
ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElementBatch(Network.getNetworkId(), batchinputs);
```

Can any one please help me, how to show multiple files on a chatter post. I see the code runs fine in the debugs, but only the visibility on the Chatter post on the page they aren't showing multiple files. Only a single file is posted.